# JavaFX runtime components are missing error in Java Gradle Project

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I started a Gradle project with java and I wanted to add JavaFx Library but when I run my application I'd got "JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application".
This is my Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

group 'org.personal'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}



dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And this is the main class:

```
package client;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class ClientApp extends Application {
   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

And this is my "Edit Configuration": [Edit Configuration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkcTb.png)

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for giving good info! I don't have an answer, but I wanted to add, though it's definitely an opinion, that I find it more convenient when images are displayed inline within the question so you don't have to use external links. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the JavaFX JDK libs to the path. Otherwise, you need to use JDK 8 (JDK1.8) which integrates the JavaFX SDK

Comment: In Edit Configuration I add  --module-path $PATH_TO_FX$ which is the path to JAvaFX libs

Comment: Yes, that's should fix the issue. I'd like to say that if you're using JDK 9+ and you set up the module-info file you need to require at least javafx.control (if you're using FXML you will also need "require javafx.fxml")

Comment: Ok.... I set up del path to fx but i didn't set up teh module info file. Where could I found it?

Comment: You must create it inside your package folder.